# Are there any guides on using differnet normal maps?

Tags: normal-map

I'm creating a character and I want want wrinkles when skin folds.  I can not put this on the main normal map obviously.  I've seen where people use black and white to mask areas where you don't want the secondary normal map to be?

Do you know what's the right approach to even doing this?

Comment: With Geometry Nodes you can calculate a tension map. That's the difference between a model in the rest pose/no active shape keys and a posed model/active shape keys. With the tension map you can mix the normal maps. Here is an example: [Procedural Tension Map for Character Wrinkle Animation with Blender Geometry Node](https://youtu.be/3jkH4N4hWcA)